# Access serilog correlationId outside logger context

Tags: asp.net, .net, correlation, serilog, x-correlation-id

How can we access the serilog correlationId outside the logger context?

I am trying to access the correlationId id inside a .net core hosted service. Since the hosted service runs background and the correlationId is null in this context. I would like to pass the correlationId id inside the hosted service dependency logger instance.

Comment: For anyone looking an answer for it. I initially searching for an answer related correlation enricher. Since corelationId gets added to response header, I was able to access the corelationId from the response header and passed it to my background service queue. So that background service can use the same correlationId of the http request that triggered this background service task. But, Over all I still did not find answer for every enricher value.